# Increase text width in KOMA scrartcl landscape

Tags: koma-script, textwidth, scrartcl

I have a KOMA `scrartcl` landscape document and would like to change/increase the textwidth. How do I do this? All the solutions I found only affect a single page or a page range. I want to do it for all of the document.

So far I just have

```
\documentclass[11pt,landscape,DIV=10]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to set a value for option `DIV`, eg.  `DIV=10`. Or you can load and use package `geometry`.

Comment: @esdd Thanks. I am already using this option (forgot in the question). I still want it wider. Regarding geometry, I read somewhere that KOMA has its own geometry commands/variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `areaset`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,landscape,DIV=10,areasetadvanced]{scrartcl}
\areaset{27cm}{\textheight}

\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{lipsum}% only dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

---

Or you can add KOMA-Script `usegeometry` to the class options. Then load package `geometry` and adjust the horizontal margins.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,landscape,DIV=10,usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{lipsum}% only dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```